# php oci_fetch_array and pass value to function issue

Tags: php, oracle, arrays

**1)** I want to save case 1 value to an array. Return this array and pass it to a function. The code become case 2, but no result come out, where is the problem?
**2)** In function display_urls, i want to echo both $url and $category. What should i do in IF condition or add another line of code?

```
function display_urls($url_array)
{
 echo "";
 if (is_array($url_array) && count($url_array)>0)
  {
   foreach ($url_array as $url)
   {
       echo "".$url."";
       echo "".$category."";
   }
 }
 echo "";
}
```

case 1: work fine

```
$result = oci_parse($conn, "select * from bookmark where username ='$username'");
if (!$result){ $err = oci_error(); exit; }
  $r = oci_execute($result);

$i=0;
echo "";
while( $row = oci_fetch_array($result) ){
   $i++;
echo "";
echo "".$row['USERNAME']."";
echo "".$row['BM_URL']."";
echo "".$row['CATEGORY']."";
echo "";
}
echo "";
```

case 2:

```
$url_array = array();
  while( $row2 = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)){
   $i++;
 $url_array[$count] = $row[0];
  }
  return $url_array;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably want something like this:

```
function display_urls($url_array)
{
 echo "";
 if (is_array($url_array) && count($url_array)>0)
  {
   foreach ($url_array as $url)
   {
       echo "".$url['BM_URL']."";
       echo "".$url['CATEGORY']."";
   }
 }
 echo "";
}

$result = oci_parse($conn, "select * from bookmark where username ='$username'");
if (!$result){ $err = oci_error(); exit; }
  $r = oci_execute($result);

$url_array = array();
while( $row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_ASSOC)){
   $url_array[] = $row;
}

display_urls($url_array);
```

This will store all the information on the URLs in $url_array with a lookup by column name.